# How to display custom fields in hestia theme

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, child-theme

I want to display my custom fields on the Posts page just next to the author’s details, date, and any other meta data of post in the listed posts.

I already have done this in Magazinenp theme ( ID:, Pages:, Format:) all these three are custom fields and display on the Posts page successfully.
Basically in Magazinenp theme, I add the code in the
templates-parts
.parts
.entry-meta.php
In comment div

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, ‘ID:’, true); ?>
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, ‘Format:’, true); ?>
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, ‘Pages:’, true); ?>
```

and it works fine.

but on Hestia theme don’t know where to put this code.

please suggest to me any other code or anything relative.

Comment: Making customizations the commercial themes is NOT recommended, since they'll be erased if the theme is ever updated.

Answer (score 0):

First, making customizations commercial themes is NOT recommended, since they'll be erased if the theme is ever updated.

It's better to use a child theme in order to make custom modifications:
https://docs.themeisle.com/article/656-how-to-create-a-child-theme-for-hestia

Second, if [this](https://github.com/Codeinwp/hestia/tree/master/template-parts) is the theme you mean, then you'll need to put the custom fields in either `template-parts/content.php`, `template-parts/content-alternative.php` or `template-parts/content-alternative-2.php`, depending on which of the theme options you've chosen.

Comment: 0


I am already using a child theme.

and already put and try the code in template-parts/content.php, template-parts/content-alternative.php or template-parts/content-alternative-2.phpin the HESTIA theme file but it did not works.

still, custom fields are not visible on the posts page.